# Xamarin cache pages - make it so input doesn't disappear

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm building my first full-scale Xamarin.Forms app and trying to figure out how to keep user input between navigation. After doing some searching online I've read that the default behavior is to completely reload pages each time you navigate, but you can change the default behavior by setting the `NavigationCacheMode` to true or required, but I've tried to set this attribute in both xaml and C# with no success - it seems like the property is not recognized.

Is there a simple way to make it so that user input does not disappear when navigating between pages? If anyone can show me how to set the NavigationCacheMode that would be great, but I'm also open to any reasonable solution that will keep the user input from disappearing during navigation.

Additional details: My app has a UWP and Android project. I am using a master detail page for navigation. Here is my MenuList_ItemSelected event handler:

```
private void MenuList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (MenuItem)e.SelectedItem;
    var title = item.Title;
    var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
    Detail = new NavigationPage(page); //TODO: when menu item is clicked and you're already on that page, the menu should just slide back. (currently it does nothing and stays out).
    IsPresented = false;
}
```

Comment: I've never had this problem.  What platform are you experiencing this on?

Comment: @Jason I'll add some additional details in the question

Comment: when you say "Navigation" do you mean selecting an item from the menu and calling MenuList_ItemSelected?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, navigating to another page (also called a view) after tapping/clicking an item on the menu on the master detail page. This triggers the MenuList_ItemSelected event handler which sets the Detail = new NavigationPage

Comment: you are creating a new instance of page every time you do that - so of course the user input will be lost

Comment: That makes sense. So how can I navigate to a page without creating a new instance?

Comment: you need to cache the page instances when you create them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to solve this! I adapted this code from a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212632/how-to-load-detailpage-once-in-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage-project) which implements a Dictionary that keeps track of the navigation stack:

In the constructor for my Master Detail Page:

```
public partial class MenuPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    Dictionary<Type, Page> menuCache = new Dictionary<Type, Page>();
}
```

Then in the ItemSelected method:

```
private void MenuList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (menuCache.Count == 0)
        menuCache.Add(typeof(AttendancePage), Detail);

    var item = (MenuItem)e.SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (menuCache.ContainsKey(item.TargetType))
        { Detail = menuCache[item.TargetType]; }
        else
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            menuCache.Add(item.TargetType, Detail);
        }

        menuList.SelectedItem = null; //solves issue with nav drawer not hiding when same item is selected twice
        IsPresented = false;
    }
}
```